# How to prevent unecessary rerenders in child components dependent on memoized parent component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

[link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/brave-flower-qjkjz1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

`App` has state from which a memoized value is computed which is passed to the `Option`s as props. When the state changes due to a callback passed to `Option`, `App` is rerendered, causing

1. a rerender of all of the `Option`s
2. a rerender of `SomeComponent` which doesn't even take any props

I am looking for a pattern using React hooks and state management that would allow for only 2 of the `Option`s to be rerendered - the one that is deselected, because its `isSelected` property goes from true to false, and the one that is selected, because its `isSelected` property goes from false to true. I do not understand why the other child components, particularly `SomeComponent`, need to be rerendered, when their props do not change.

Comment: This is how React works. A re-render of a component will trigger a re-render of all children. What you're attempting to do is an over-optimization, and may actually result in a performance loss rather than the gain you expect. Re-renders are very very fast, and a re-render does not mean any changes are made to the actual DOM. Just trust React to do it's job well until you notice an observable performance problem.

Comment: Interesting - so am I correct in saying that the render method being called in code (as determined by console logging in the body of the React functional component) corresponds to a write to the virtual DOM? Then React does its magic to determine whether it needs to update the real DOM?

Comment: Yes. The JSX we write first get's executed to return objects that represent the DOM (`console.log(<SomeComponent />)` to see what I mean). Then React compares the new Virtual DOM with the previous, and determines what places need to actually change.

Comment: See [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) for a better and more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically done with React.memo to make components who's render is only dependant on their props not re-render unless their props change.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo